# In Jquery bx slider plugin how to find the current slider is image or video

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, bxslider

How to find the current slider is an image or a video in bx slider.

If it is a video then the video has to reload if it is an image then do not reload. 
But I am using that the image and video both are reloaded when I go to the next slider.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".bxslider").bxSlider({  
        onSlideNext: function(){  
            var iframe = $("#frameid").attr('src');  
            $("#frameid").attr('src', iframe);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(ELE).prop('tagName')` to get the element' tagName.
`<video>` has tagName `VIDEO` while `<img>` has tagName `IMG`. So you can then do different actions base on that.

Or use `.is('video')` to check if target element is video, as you only want to reload `video`.

So you can write as :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".bxslider").bxSlider({  
    onSlideNext: function() {
      var $target = $("#frameid");
      // Another way
      // if ($target.prop('tagName') === 'VIDEO') {
      if ($target.is('video')) {
        var iframe = $target.attr('src');  
        $target.attr('src', iframe);
      }
    }  
  });  
});
```

P.S: If you just want the `video` to play from start, I'd suggest use

```
// Set video to start.
video.currentTime = 0;
// If the video has autoplay requirement.
video.play();
```

As this won't load the video again but just set video to its start point, it won't cost additional traffic to reload the video.

Snippet:

```js
// TagName
console.log($('#im').prop('tagName'));
console.log($('#vi').prop('tagName'));
// .Is
console.log($('#im').is('video'));
console.log($('#vi').is('video'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="im"/>
<video id="vi"></video>
```